# How to prevent $LS_COLORS ex from overriding *.extension color settings

Tags: bash, terminal

I am configuring my ls color scheme for Ubuntu terminal. Currently everything is working except any and all files containing the executable permission are overridden by ex regardless of whether or not they are set by *.extension.

my LS_COLORS line: `LS_COLORS="*.py=00;33:fi=00;00:di=01;34" export LS_COLORS`

This is a problem because the large codebase I inherited has given many of the files the executable permission. This isn't something I can change, so I am stuck with having every executable file colored the same. I want to be able to set my .py files as one color and my .sh files (etc) as another, but since they both have the executable permission I can't.

Is there any way to ignore ex completely (I'd just make individual rules for .sh, .py etc). Or can I somehow rearrange the order in which the rules are applied to make ex first and *.extension last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the compiled-in value for "exec", e.g.,

```
LS_COLORS="*.py=00;33:fi=00;00:di=01;34:ex=0" export LS_COLORS
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I incorrectly tried doing this by setting ex to the default color (ex=00;00). I didn't know you could just turn it off by setting it to 0.